# Masstransit: where can I set RabbitMQ Delivery Mode to make a message Persistent?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I found some old examples of this, but none of them works anymore because the methods aren't there anymore. Take a look:

```
bus.PublishRequest("Hello",
    callback =>
    {
        callback.Handle<string>(_ => { });
        callback.HandleFault(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
        callback.SetTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    },
    context =>
    {
        context.SetDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.InMemory);
    });
```

This comes from an old github [issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/258).

I'm using MassTransit v5.3.2 and Masstransit.DeliveryMode is not present, nor is SetDeliveryMode.

How MassTransit deals with these options? How can I make sure that my messages will be persisted in a broker failure/restart?

I'm trying to build a resilient highly available message bus, but I can't find enough information on the topic.

Comment: When using RabbitMQ, all messages are durable by default. So there isn't any reason to worry about it.

Comment: Looking at MassTransit source code, I found the "RabbitMqSendTransport.SendPipe.Send" method that contains an interesting instruction: "properties.Persistent = context.Durable;". Given this, I can assume that in MassTransit I can't set the DeliveryMode anymore. If I set the queue Durable equals true, then the message will atomatically be of type Persistent. @ChrisPatterson, can you confirm this?

Comment: Correct. Durable is the _default_, so you don't need to specify it at all.